# what is the way to use .cert for external services( using https) in openshift pod / docker container?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, openshift, cacerts

My spring boot application is connecting with API connect which is using *https* API's. I am able to communicate with API connect on local as I have installed the cert file provided by them using keytool in security/cacert of JDK. but inside openshift environment I can't figure out how to do this. Please help I'm new to this. Thank you.
[Openshift(springapp)] --------(https://)*needs cacert*-------> [API Connect]